# Piecewise function for least squares fit python

Tags: python, numpy, least-squares, piecewise

I’m trying to extract 8 parameters from 3 measurements.
For this to happen on 3 measures at the same time, I go through a part-by-part function.
This technique works with optimize.curvefit but I can’t force the program to get a proper error on my settings. The conditions are too quickly met.

So I now try to use leastsquare because I know I can adjust the gap that I want between my data and fitted'parameters with fscale.
Unfortunately I get the following error message : "NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 29 input values to the 1 output values where the mask is true" and I block in its resolution.

Thanks for your help.

```
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

l, t = [], []
with open("Test.txt", "r") as f_read:
    for line in f_read:
        line = line.strip()  #suppression du retour charriot en fin de ligne
        if line:
            ti, vi = [float(elt) for elt in line.split("\t")]  #conversion en nb
            l.append(ti), t.append(vi)

for i in range(len(t)-7) :
    t[i]=(np.sin(t[i]/180*np.pi))**2

t=np.array(t)
l=np.array(l)


def fun1(A,x,y):
    f=A[0]+A[1]/(x**2-A[2])-A[3]*x**2
    return f-y

def fun2(A,x,y):
    f=A[4]+A[5]/(x**2-A[6])-A[7]*x**2
    return f-y

def fun3(A,x,y):
    no=1/(A[0]+A[1]/(x**2-A[2])-A[3]*(x**2))
        
    ne=1/(A[4]+A[5]/(x**2-A[6])-A[7]*(x**2))
        
    no2=1/(A[0]+A[1]/((x/2)**2-A[2])-A[3]*((x/2)**2))
        
    f=(no2-no)/(ne-no)
    return f-y

def fun4(A,x,y):    
    
    x=x-2
    l2=1.064
    l3=(1/x+1/l2)**(-1)
    no3=np.sqrt(A[0]+A[1]/(l3**2-A[2])-A[3]*(l3**2))
    no1=1/(A[0]+A[1]/(x**2-A[2])-A[3]*(x**2))
    ne1=1/(A[4]+A[5]/(x**2-A[6])-A[7]*(x**2))
    no2=1/(A[0]+A[1]/(l2**2-A[2])-A[3]*(l2**2))
    ne2=1/(A[4]+A[5]/(l2**2-A[6])-A[7]*(l2**2))
    
    X=(no1*(np.cos(y*180/np.pi))**2+ne1*(np.sin(y*180/np.pi))**2)**(-1/2)
    Y=(no2*(np.cos(y*180/np.pi))**2+ne2*(np.sin(y*180/np.pi))**2)**(-1/2)
    f=no3/l3-X/x-Y/l2
    return f
        

A=2.84507614e+00
B=1.37848818e-02
C=3.68428479e-02
D=2.43158022e-03
E=2.88095276e+00
F=3.12234625e-02
G=2.40374019e-02
H=3.88776226e-03
p0 = np.array([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H])

def piecewise_linear(A,x,y):
    x0 = 0.7
    x1 = 1
    x2 = 3
    
    return np.piecewise(x, 
                        [x < x0, 
                         (x >= x0) & (x < x1),
                         (x >= x1) & (x < x2),
                         x >= x2], 
                        [lambda x: fun1(A,x,y), 
                         lambda x: fun2(A,x,y),
                         lambda x: fun3(A,x,y),
                         lambda x: fun4(A,x,y)])
  
p = least_squares(piecewise_linear, p0, loss='soft_l1', f_scale=0.0001, args=(l, t)
                            , max_nfev=100000)
print(p.x)
```

Comment: Anyone can help me this problem ?